# Почему результаты этих программ отличаются?

Tags: java

Вывод этой прораммы 104745Ж

```
        int counter = 1, num = 10001, ourPrime = 3;

        while (counter != num) {
            if (PrimeNumber.isPrime(ourPrime)) counter++;
            if (counter != num) ourPrime += 2;
        }
```

Вывод этой программы 104743:

```
        int counter = 1, num = 10001, ourPrime = 3;

        while (counter != num) {
            if (PrimeNumber.isPrime(ourPrime)) counter++;
            ourPrime += 2;
        }
```

Вот код функции isPrime, если что:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int num) {

    if (num < 2) return false;

    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) if (num % i == 0) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: А почему он должен быть одинаковым? И вообще, каким он должен быть на ваш взгляд?

Comment: в первом случае когда счетчик становится равным `counter == num`, срабатывает условиe `if()` и `ourPrime += 2` не выполняется. А во втором случае - выполняется всегда. поэтому во втором случае `ourPrime` на 2 больше. Т.к. сначала идет проверка условия цикла, и только потом счетчик увеличивается.

Answer (score 0):

В первой программе присутствует повторная проверка внутри цикла `while`:
`if (counter != num)`
Во второй программе цикл выполняет `ourPrime += 2;` в любом случае, а в первой не выполняет в ходе последней итерации цикла `while`, так как переменная `counter` стала равна `num` и прямо в теле цикла была произведена проверка.
Это происходит потому что после изменения переменной `counter` в теле цикла, все тело цикла сначала выполняется до конца и только потом происходит проверка условия `while (counter != num)`